# Regular expression to match optional tags (sqaure brackets)... (find & replace in SQL queries, Notepad++)

Tags: sql, regex, notepad++, database-schema, find-replace

I am trying to construct a regular expression that will find and replace occurrences of certain SQL schema qualifications in over 100 SQL files.

The original files can contain schema qualifications that may(**optionally**) have square brackets (`'['` and `']'`) or not. For example a script file may contain:

```sql
[database].[dbo].[table_name]
```

or

```sql
database.[dbo].[table_name]
```

or

```sql
database.dbo.[table_name]
```

and all possible combinations...

I wrote something like this:

```regex
([)?database(])?\.([)?dbo(]?)\.([?)table_name(]?)
```

[Not really working](https://regex101.com/r/Rz9MLB/1) (regex101)

**Update (with solution based on answer):**

Expansion based on @Toto's selected answer below, with addition of a possible table alias to match following string and provision of space prefixes and suffixes

```sql
database.dbo.table_name  tn
```

```regex
(\s+)(\[)?database(\])?\.(\[)?dbo(\]?)\.(\[?)table_name(\]?)((\s+)(tn))?(\s+)?
```

https://regex101.com/r/Rz9MLB/7

Comment: You have to escape the square brackets as they are special in regex.

Comment: Do you consider `database.dbo.table_name]` as valid?

Comment: Yes it would be invalid @SahilGulati. A more fool-proof expression would catch that issue. Though in my case it would not happen because the scripts are stored procedures that are **already residing in SQL Server... it's own error checking wouldn't even allow you to create or alter a stored procedure with that scenario**....I am sure it will still be helpful to a general case though

Comment: okay.. fine. :)

Comment: There was no need to delete your solution though. I believe it would still be helpful to someone. Had upvoted it. Feel free to re-add it, as I believe it is still relevant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to escape the square brackets as they are special in regex.

And the groups are superfluous, your regex becomes:

```
\[?database\]?\.\[?dbo\]?\.\[?table_name\]?
```

Comment: Thank-you! That did it.

Comment: You can also add `\s`(or something better) ,which is useful if you already did a previous search and would not want to, say, find and replace on an already replaced string... in my case, I was prefixing the entire schema qualification with a server name for a linked server scenario

Comment: This answer is matching an invalid sequence. database.dbo.table_name]

Comment: I am having a bit of a challenge as I add more to the expression. Maybe you could help... I am now trying to match an optional table alias, but in all cases there should be a space suffix after the string. I have something like `(\s+)(\[)?database(\])?\.(\[)?dbo(\]?)\.(\[?)table_name(\]?)(\s+tn)?\s+`. But it will not match the other potential scenarios: https://regex101.com/r/Rz9MLB/8

Comment: Ok, this seems to work so far: `(\s+)(\[)?database(\])?\.(\[)?dbo(\]?)\.(\[?)table_name(\]?)(\s+tn)?\s`